# Control not transferring in JSP Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  

     var index_x;
        function ajax_login(s,u,p)
        {   
            index_x=new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url="control.jsp?uid="+u+"&sid="+s+"&pwd="+p;
            index_x.onreadystatechange=show_ajaxlogin;
            index_x.open("GET",url,true);
            index_x.send(null);
        }
        function show_ajaxlogin()
        {
            if(index_x.readyState==4 ||index_x.readyState==200)
            {   
                    document.getElementById("forgot").innerHTML=index_x.responseText;
            }

        }

        </script>
```

When i call this function ajax_login(s,u,p) by button click, function is working but control is not transferring to control.jsp

Comment: This question is poorly written - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read the link I gave in my first comment about what we expect from questions

Comment: Can u plz suggest me the solution, if u know!

Comment: @GaganBhatia, post your code completely in which areas you are suppose strucks. Your question is not meeting exact problem. see my asnwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In login `jsp`

```
       <script>
       function ajax_login(u) {         
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);//to check whether the response is coming or not
                document.getElementById("forgot").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","control.jsp?uid="+u+"&pwd="+document.getElementById("password").value,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>


   <input type="password" value="some" id="pass" name="pwd"/>
   <button id="empid" value='emp001' onclick='ajax_login(this.value);'>Login</button>
```

When clicks on the above Login button, `ajax_login(.)` function will be called having value `emp001`.

In `control.jsp`

```
    <%=request.getParameter("uid");>//checking form parameter value
    <%=request.getParameter("pwd");>
```

This is only sample code to helps.